# Issue upgrading SpringBoot from 2.2.4 to 2.7.2 - Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

I have a SpringBoot application with the following version. I plan to update `spring-boot-starter-parent` to 2.7.2.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

When I change the version to 2.7.2 and run the code, I get the below error.

```
ERROR [main] TomcatStarter:61 onStartup - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'beanConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'TokenServices': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authProfileImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/connection/DefaultClusterFactory
```

I tried searching for the error messages over the internet, however, I couldn't figure out any solution.

I need suggestions on the steps to troubleshoot the issue in order to identify the solution.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` typically means that you have some version conflict for some dependencies. In this case with `com.mongodb.xxxx` dependency. You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to check transitive dependencies and possible conflicts

Comment: Hi @Alex, thank you for your advice. After checking the dependency tree and other readings, I identified that the class `com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory` is removed from `mongodb-driver`. This class is available in `mongo-java-driver`. Adding this dependency solved the issue.

Do you want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` typically means that you have some version conflict for some dependencies. In this case with `com.mongodb.xxxx` dependency.

It looks like `com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory` was moved from `mongodb-driver` into `mongo-java-driver` and according to @Sahil Khanna it fixes the issue, but, for spring projects, to avoid such issues in the future better to avoid direct dependencies to mongo and rely on standard Spring Data MongoDB dependencies managed by Spring BOM if possible [Developing with Spring Boot - Dependency Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.build-systems.dependency-management)

> The curated list contains all the Spring modules that you can use with Spring Boot as well as a refined list of third party libraries. The list is available as a standard Bills of Materials (spring-boot-dependencies) that can be used with both Maven and Gradle.